# Como retornar um valor no formato moeda brasileiro na view do Django?

Tags: python, django

Como retornar o valor `1768` no formato moeda BRL `1.768,00` na view do Django?

```
def moeda(request):
    valor = 1768
    # formata o valor
    return HttpResponse('Valor: %s' % valor)
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Têm duas formas simples de se fazer isso, a seguir:

**1) utilizando localize:**

```
from django.utils.formats import localize
def moeda(request):
    valor = 1768 
    valor = localize(valor)
    return HttpResponse('Valor: %s' % valor)
    # resultado: Valor: 1.768,00
```

**2) utilizando locale:**

```
import locale
def moeda(request):
    valor = 1768 
    locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'pt_BR.UTF-8')
    valor = locale.currency(valor, grouping=True, symbol=None)
    return HttpResponse('Valor: %s' % valor)
    # resultado: Valor: 1.768,00
```

Answer (score 13):

Minha estratégia é mais simples e direta:

Utilizo a formatação padrão ( a mesma do dolar ) e apenas inverto '.' e ',':

```
def real_br_money_mask(my_value):
    a = '{:,.2f}'.format(float(my_value))
    b = a.replace(',','v')
    c = b.replace('.',',')
    return c.replace('v','.')
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O legal dessa abordagem é que não precisa fazer nenhum import.

Answer (score 1):

eu pude observar que o erro estava no nome "pt_BR.UTF-8". 
Ao menos para o meu Python (3.6), para setar o formato texto para o Brasil, eu usei: "Portuguese_Brazil.1252"

Segue minha solução para o problema de vocês:

```
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, "Portuguese_Brazil.1252")
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.rcParams['axes.formatter.use_locale'] = True
```

Espero que ajude.

Comment: O valor dependerá do sistema operacional. No Linux você pode listar os possíveis valores executando `locale -a` no terminal.

Answer (score 1):

Com somente uma linha de código e sem importar nada:

```
valor = 1768

valor_real = "R${:,.2f}".format(valor).replace(",", "X").replace(".", ",").replace("X", ".")
```

Answer (score 0):

Usando Python 3 no Windows 7 (já em pt-BR), encontrei o seguinte resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Utilizando `locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'pt_BR.UTF-8')`, resultou:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Entretanto, não testei com Python 2.

Comment: Mesma coisa aqui com python 2.7

Answer (score 0):

Para Formatar em Real sem usar função:

```
import locale
    
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_MONETARY, 'pt_BR.UTF-8')  
  
valor_em_Real_formatado = locale.currency(12.4593681)
print(valor_em_Real_formatado)
```